# Raspberry Pi outside local network - configure at home?

Tags: ssh, remote, port-forwarding, accessibility

Raspberry Pi newbie here!

I want to be able to access my Raspberry Pi outside my local network. I have read some guides on how to do this by using port forwarding and SSH. It sounds do-able.

In my case I will have to configure everything from home, and then the raspberry will be used in a remote location. (I will not myself go but will send it with colleagues.) Is it possible to configure everything from my home and then just plug it in this remote location, and access it from my home computer, if I have the IP-address to the Raspberry Pi? Or do I have to make the configuration in this remote place myself to access it?

Comment: Please add information like, have you searched for a solution?
What router type do you have?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this via port forwarding, then your colleagues will need to configure the router / firewall at the remote location. This may or may not be possible depending on a variety of factors, including but not limited to: 1. Whether they have access to the router / firewall to make changes, 2. whether something else on the remote network is already using the ports that you want to forward.

The only way that I know to make your remote Pi run automatically is if you configure it to connect back to your home via some VPN.  In this case, it will initiate the connection to you rather than the other way around.

There will be several challenges to this, however, so it's not really a "newbie" thing to try.  In any case, you'll need more resources than you can get on one question here. Among the challenges in this:

1. Configuring the VPN may be tricky even under "controlled" circumstances.
2. Your IP address at home probably changes from time to time, which will break a naïve attempt to do this.
3. Making the remote box autonomous in the face of inevitable VPN drops may make the problems still harder.

These problems are surmountable, but they are not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this post is kinda old, but I think I might have some useful info.

I would try using remote.it. It allows you to access your pi from anywhere as long as it has a route to the internet or even cellular. You dont need to use port forwarding with them, but you can still use SSH or VNC

You can make a free account at https://www.remot3.it/web/index.html and install the installer on your pi while at home. With this you do not need to configure it in the remote location.

Full disclosure: Im actually interning at remote.it this summer, but thought this info might help you.